# I'm using the Struts2-jQuery grid plugin and the action is called twice

Tags: jquery, struts, struts2-jquery, jqgrid, struts2-json-plugin

I follow the example listed [here](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) when I load the page or press any button on the grid the method execute is called twice. I want to call it just once. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename (or remove, since in the example is not used) the getJSON method.

```
public String getJSON()
{
   return execute();
}
```

JSON plugin may be calling all your methods that start with "get" in an attempt to serialize them for output.

See: 
[Struts2 Action being called twice if result type is json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061709/struts2-action-being-called-twice-if-result-type-is-json)

**Edit:**

You can also use the includeProperties or excludeProperties params to avoid the default behavior of call all the methods that start with "get", see: [Problem with Json plugin in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648288/problem-with-json-plugin-in-struts-2)

Comment: I've added an alternative solution, I'm glad to help you.